# turtlebot Roomba/ Create power issues

Tags: ros, roomba, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know what the internal power checking  routines on a Roomba do  and how they work?  I am thinking they don't look just at the voltage, but may have some way to sense current. ( I am working with a Roomba 500 series base).

I am guessing if it is over 15v?  it thinks it is on charge,  and below some other voltage 13?  it needs to be charged.  I am struggling with multiple dead roomba battery packs.  If I can feed a fixed voltage through the external unregulated power connector,
perhaps I can better manage performance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27623/turtlebot-roomba/-create-power-issues./) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2012-02-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general the charging logic for the roomba/create is not the best. Typically the roomba/create batteries charge to something like 15-17V and below about 13V it shuts off. On the create the charging logic will not try to charge a battery after it have been through one charging cycle and will let a battery completely drain until it is unplugged and re-plugged in.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on 2012-02-19**:
Is the logic the same on the Roomba and what is the logic?  I've tried using an accessory battery -  but the dashboard acts as if it isn't there or can't be detected.  The Roomba knows when it is on or off the charger, but switching it to full mode seems hit or miss.